# How to call AngularJS script with argument to load Html elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, vba, web-scraping

I'm On a web-scraping project but the url contains AngularJS which I'm not familiar with. I have trouble accessing Html elements probably produced by AngularJS based which "handicapOption" is currently active.

The web, for testing purposes, I'm Practicing on this
[URL](https://www.tvg.com/racetracks/SKB/south-korea-busan?race=1)

URL might not be available by the time people sees this question so heres a link where available races can be found.
https://www.tvg.com/races

And here's a relevant portion of the HTML

```html
<div class="group">
  <h2 class="runners-table-title">Race Card</h2>
  <div class="handicapOption" qa-label="handicapOption">
    <h3>Handicapping
      <!----><span ng-if="$root.activeFeatures.tooltipHandicapping" tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip-template="selectedHandicaping.helpTemplateUrl"><i class="tvg-icon-help"></i></span>
      <!---->
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <!---->
      <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a class="active" href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Summary</a></li>
      <!---->
      <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Snapshot</a></li>
      <!---->
      <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Speed &amp; Class</a></li>
      <!---->
      <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Pace</a></li>
      <!---->
      <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Jockey/Trainer Stats</a></li>
      <!---->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, When I click Element-B (Snapshot) -> the second `<li>` element, both Element-A (Summary) and Element-B switches its name as shown below

```html
  <li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Summary</a></li>

<li ng-repeat="option in handicapingOptions"><a class="active" href="" ng-class="{'active': selectedHandicaping === option}" qa-label="handicapOptionValue" ng-click="selectHandicapping(option)">Snapshot</a></li>
```

and then it displays a different table.

That is what I was trying to simulate via VBA. Unfortunately, The table element does not get updated. And I was assiming that this function is called 
"selectHandicapping(option)"
Can anybody teach me how? P.S. I have no idea how to supply value for argument option or what kind of data the argument option is.

So I've been digging and googling about this for this whole week and finally decided to spit the question. I tried calling ".Click" and firing "onChange" event but to no avail. I could not Load Snapshot contents table via code

And here is my VBA Code

```
    Public Sub LoadHorses()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = Core.API_.Explorer
    ie.Navigate oRaceTrack.RaceUrl & "?race=" & RaceNumber
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      Application.StatusBar = "Requesting " & Title & " Horse Data"
      DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim oHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set oHTMLDoc = ie.Document
    Do While Not oHTMLDoc.ReadyState = "complete"
      Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & Title & " data, please wait"
      DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim handicapOption As Object
    Dim currentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
    Set currentWindow = oHTMLDoc.parentWindow
    Dim oTbl As HTMLTable
    For Each handicapOption In oHTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
      If handicapOption.innerText = "Summary" Then
      'I was able to extract data from Summary tab because this is the default tab that is active
        handicapOption.Click
        handicapOption.Focus
        Set oTbl = oHTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("table race-handicapping-results")(0)

        Dim oRow As HTMLTableRow
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Length - 1
          Set oRow = oTbl.Rows(i)
          If oRow.className = "program-page-runner runner" Then
            Dim h As Horse
            Set h = New Horse
            h.HorseNumber = oRow.Cells(0).innerText
            h.HorseName = SplitGetPart(Replace(Trim(oRow.Cells(2).innerText), Chr(13), ""), 2, Chr(10))
            h.DaysOff = 0
            h.PowerRating = 0
            oRaceHorses.Add h
          End If
        Next i

      ElseIf handicapOption.innerText = "Snapshot" Then
        handicapOption.Click 'Does not work
        handicapOption.Focus 'Does not work
        handicapOption.fireevent "onChange" 'Does not work
        handicapOption.fireevent "onClick" 'Does not work
        'handicapOption.setActive => causes error
        'oHTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "selectHandicapping(option)" 'Causes error

        Set oTbl = oHTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("table race-handicapping-results")(0)
        '<-Extract Snapshot Table

        '->
        End If
      Next handicapOption
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use a headless browser to allow the javascript to render content

Comment: @charlietfl What does it mean? I have no problem rendering the contents on my problem, I just cant invoke the click event via VBA, but if I go to the browser and click it, the page works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following as an example of selecting the tabs to click through. In your script I think you need to be logged in at the start as for me it prompts for this. After logging in, if required, use the syntax as shown below to gather a nodeList of the tabs to click though. You want to click on the `a` tag element within each `li`

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub RetrieveInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, tabs As Object, i As Long
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.tvg.com/racetracks/FRE/freehold-raceway/autoplay/true?race=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set tabs = .document.querySelectorAll(".group li a")
        For i = 1 To tabs.Length - 1 'ignore first tab Summary
            tabs.item(i).Click 'click through tabs
        Next

        Stop

    End With
End Sub
```